# Laravel - Accessing array inside of an array

Tags: php, laravel

Code:

```
    @if(Cart::count() > 0)
        @php
            dd(Cart::content());
        @endphp
    @endif
```

[image: DD result]

How can I access the "**options**" array?
I can access id,qty & etc by simply running:

```
            @foreach(Cart::content() as $item)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->qty}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->price}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

But `$item[options]->size` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart#models) of the package that you are using, you can access related models as properties. If Options is a model so:

```
$item->options->size
```

Would do the job.